# Why is SignUpSignInPolicyId required for an API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web

This sample here shows providing a `SignUpSignInPolicyId` https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C

[See the appsettings.json for the **service** (Web API)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/TodoListService/appsettings.json):

```json
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6",
    "Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi_reset_v2",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi_reset_v2"
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  },
```

I am confused what this does with an API, the API is protected by OAuth2 JWT it cannot control sign up or sign in at all. It just takes a token and validates it.

Why does it need to know anything at all about a sign up or sign in policy?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run the application which calls api with policy ,I can login and open the redirect to app.

[image]

**Appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://kavyab2c.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "kavyab2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile" // Optional profile editing policy
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  },
```

[image]

Even without policy it redirected to page.

[image]

But to obtain claims or reach the particular controller action or access an api,  it requires user authentication if one needs to protect API.

[image]

Note:
***SignUpSignInPolicyId should not be omitted when calling an Azure AD B2C protected API. If it is not specidfied, the API will not know which user flow to use  and cant authenticate the user  and gives error.***

> If custompolicy is used instead of userflow, the SignUpSignInPolicyId
> parameter can be omitted, and the created  custom policy can be used
> to authenticate and authorize users directly by making use of their
> username and password credentials.

**Reference:** [Cloud authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0#modify-the-app)

Comment: It just seems odd to me that my WEB app, could ever use a different user flow than my API. Because with the current config settings, that is entirely possible. And I understand that my API might cause a challenge, and specify the use where to redirect but its an API with a bearer token so that does not make any sense.